# Using an Oracle tnsnames.ora with DataGrip

Tags: oracle, datagrip, intellij-datagrip

I am new to Oracle and trying to figure out how to connect DataGrip to it.  Here is a screen shot of where what I am seeing:

[image]
For what it is worth, the tnsnames.ora works find for Oracle SQL Developer, so I don't know why DateGrip is having problems.

Comment: If this is on Windows, as suggested by the "D:' reference,then shouldn't those delimiters be '\' instead of '/' ?  Show us definitive proof that 'D:/app/sam.carleton/product/11.2.0/client_1/Network/Admin/tnsnames.ora' actually exists.

Comment: When you get into software that is cross platform such as Java and Qt, they no longer care which slash you use and they tend to default to forward slash since that is what most of the OS's use these days.  For what it is worth... I have tried both, neither work and when I click on the [...] button to the right of the path, it converts to forward slash.

Comment: As far as proving the file exists... other than the screen show above where BEHIND the DataGrid window I am showing Windows Explorer that is showing the full path and the file itself, I don't know how to prove that to you other than letting you remote into my machine.  What proof are you looking for?  P.S.  Oracle SQL Developer reads that file fine.

Comment: Kumar, I am new at this company and they only provided TNS connection info.  It turns out that your first suggestion worked, setting the system variable, thank you!

Comment: Yes, some GUI seem to be able to handle '\' vs. '/' interchangeably, translating behind the covers for the specific OS, which certainly _does_ care.  As for proof of the existence of a file, best is simply a command prompt 'dir'  (or 'ls', for *nix) command, with formatted copy and paste back to your opening question.  Some products impose their own value for TNS admin, others don't and simply go with the default path to tnsnames.ora.  TNS admin is only required if tnsnames.ora is not in the default location..

Comment: Hi! I'm Alexander from DG team. Have you added this path using `...` button? Please try entering some alias from that file in `TNS Name` field and see if it works. We pass everything to oracle driver in UI it is used only to populate completion for that field. This will help to tell if it is UI-only problem. Also, it would be easier to solve such issues in our bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

Comment: @kassak I did use the [...] button and still got the message, I finally got things working when I set the TNS_ADMIN environment variable and the error message went away.  Now I do have to manually add the alias, but it is working!  P.S.  I don't understand your whole bug tracker comment, please feel free to email me at my gmail account, it is <first letter of first name><last name>@...  My name is in the screen shot.

Comment: Follow instructions from [DataGrip official help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/connecting-to-a-database.html#connect-to-oracle-database) and [Oracle TNS names help](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/tnsnames.htm#NETRF007)